# How do I sum up speed through space and time to obtain c (in terms of units)?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light

I'm still learning SR and only recently I could scratch the surface of such beautiful, complex and deep topic.

[This post here](http://www.pbs.org/wgbh/nova/physics/special-relativity-nutshell.html) was really enlightening, and even though it is somewhat basic, it helped me clarify a lot the whole concept of our "daily travel through space-time".

If I got the whole thing right, then the closer I get to the speed of light while travelling through space, the closer I become to 0 in my "travel through time". In such a way that:

$$c = spaceSpeed + timeSpeed$$

Is this correct?

If so, examining the units in the equation we have:

$$c=\frac{m}{s} $$
$$spaceSpeed=\frac{m}{s} $$
$$timeSpeed=\frac{s}{s}=1=unitless? $$

Is this also correct? Our "speed through time" is measured in $\frac{s}{s}$, which yields to a constant?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-velocity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Time in special relativity is measured as a distance, obtained by multiplying a time interval by $c$.

What Brian Greene is on about here is that in special relativity, we assign a special spatial coordinate $w = ct$ to every event and consider it as a "four-vector" $[w, x, y, z]$. Now, what is a four-vector? Well, they have one key role in special relativity: in this mathematics of four-vectors, for each pair of 4-vectors $\mathbf u = [a, b, c, d]$ and $\mathbf v = [e, f, g, h]$, everybody in the universe agrees on their *inner product*, which is the number$$\mathbf u \cdot \mathbf v = a e - b f - c g - d h$$In turn, we also agree that $\mathbf u + \mathbf v = [a + e, b + f, c + g, d + h]$ is another 4-vector with this magical "everyone agrees on the inner-product" property, as is the scalar product $k ~\mathbf u = [k a, k b, k c, k d]$.

The coordinate transformations which preserve this $(+ - - -)$ inner product are known as the "Lorentz group" of transformations. They consist of usual rotations and reflections among $x, y, \text{ and } z$ combined with reflections of $w$ and a special operation that mixes space and time, the **Lorentz boost**. The boost in the $z$ direction, for example, is parametrized by a number usually called $\beta$ and a special derived number $\gamma = 1/\sqrt{1 - \beta^2}$, to be:
$$w' = \gamma ~ (w - \beta ~ z);~~x' = x;~~y'=y;~~z' = \gamma~(z - \beta~w)$$**Exercise**: confirm that after doing this pattern to $\mathbf u$ and $\mathbf v$, you get the same value of $\mathbf u \cdot \mathbf v$.

So this Lorentz boost is the "correct" way to think about changing to a reference frame that is moving relative to another one. In fact the expansion of $\gamma$ is second-order in $\beta$, so to first order approximation, what happens for small transfers $\beta$ is:

1. All positions must be changed from $z \rightarrow z - v ~t$, where $v = \beta ~ c$ is the "speed" that we are boosting by. (That $v$ is the speed we are boosting by is not actually an approximation: imagine a particle moving with $z = v~t$, the Lorentz boost formula gives $\gamma (z - \beta~c~t) = \gamma (v t - v t) = \gamma 0 = 0$.)
2. All times must be changed from $t \rightarrow t - v ~z/c^2$. We might have thought that remote clocks which the one reference frame thought were "in sync" would stay "in sync" in the moving reference frame, but they actually do *not*. They slowly fall out of sync the further and further you are from this point.

The "time dilation" and "length contraction" effects due to $\gamma$ can therefore be understood as the aggregate effects of the continuum of "de-syncing" that these clocks are undergoing.

As a special case, of course, if you have two events at $(w_0, x_0, y_0, z_0)$ and $(w_1, x_1, y_1, z_1)$ then there is a number which everyone agrees on between them, called their **spacetime interval**, $$I = (w_1 - w_0)^2 - (x_1 - x_0)^2 - (y_1 - y_0)^2 - (z_1 - z_0)^2.$$ I mention this because I need to call attention to the fact that this can either be positive, corresponding to a "timelike separation" between the events, where one happens "after" the other; or negative, corresponding to a "spacelike separation" between the events, where they definitely happen at different places. Everyone can therefore either agree on the "proper time" $\sqrt{I}/c$ between two events which are timelike separated, or the "proper distance $\sqrt{-I}/c$ between two events which are spacelike separated.

The proper time is actually observed by the clock of a spaceship which is "at both events as they happen." The proper distance is actually observed by the rulers of a spaceship which thinks both events happened "simultaneously". But everyone can use their own coordinates to figure out what they both are.

Now consider a particle which I describe as moving in this $z$ direction at speed $v$: it has 4-position $[c~t, 0, 0, v~t]$. But when I want to talk about *4-velocity* I therefore cannot divide this by $t$, a time interval which everyone measures differently. I must instead measure the time as the particle's proper time, which everyone agrees on. This proper time is $\tau = \sqrt{c^2 t^2 - v^2 t^2}/c = t ~ \sqrt{1 - v^2/c^2}$. If you allow me to abuse notation by again defining $\beta = v/c$ and $\gamma = 1/\sqrt{1 - \beta^2}$ we have the formula $\tau = t/\gamma$ or that the proper 4-velocity is$$\frac{d\mathbf r}{d\tau} = \gamma [c, 0, 0, v].$$
**Exercise**: work out $\frac{d\mathbf r}{d\tau} \cdot \frac{d\mathbf r}{d\tau} = c^2$. Every particle is, in the 4-vector sense, moving at speed $c$ -- does this surprise you? If so, do the above Lorentz boost to the particle's 4-position, so that you are transitioning to a frame where the particle is at rest. Is it more obvious now why every particle has "speed" $c$ in the 4-vector sense?

If you complete the last exercise, you will fully understand what Greene is talking about: every velocity in the 4-vector sense has magnitude $c$ but when we boost into a frame where that vector is moving, part of that magnitude lies "in the direction of its motion" and so to us it seems to be moving "not so fast" through time.

Comment: The OP won't understand any of this. Moreover, it's probably better to express spatial distances as a function of time of flight of light rather than the other way around. That's how it's now defined experimentally, by the way: "The meter is the length of the path travelled by light in vacuum during a time interval of 1/299792458 of a second.". Why is this better? Because time is defined locally, whereas space is not.

Comment: Big thanks Chris!! I don't know if you have any experience with computer graphics API's (DirectX or OpenGL), but your explanation of 4-vector reminded me a lot about the vectors used in computer graphics: [x, y, z, w]. w is assumed to be 1 for all points, and when it is not 1, once this points has its coordinates changed from their space to the viewer's space, it will appear "distorted" or "misplaced" to the viewer. I know it is just a mere coincidence but your answer, along with the other one, helped me get the overall idea. I still have a long way ahead :)

Comment: @carlosrafaelgn There is in fact an idea which is very similar to computer graphics: projecting incoming light rays on a "celestial sphere" so their 4-vectors are $(|\vec r|, -\vec r)$. With patience and stereographic coordinates, you can discover that a relativistic ball passing by you will always appear "round" (its Lorentz contraction is "invisible" and appears as a "Terrell rotation") and as you speed up the stars "tilt" into the direction you're going. [MIT released a game](http://gamelab.mit.edu/games/a-slower-speed-of-light/) exploring this sort of stuff.

Comment: @carlosrafaelgn The reason that this idea is very similar to computer graphics is not just this notion of a "camera plane", but also that in both cases the correct mathematics  is basically one of spinors/quaternions. If you really want a tour-de-force through all of this stuff, complete with a technical overview of differential geometry, check out Penrose's *Spinors and Space-Time*, vol. 1.

Comment: Well Chris, thanks again! I will download this game (which I was unaware of) and will dive deeper into many of the math concepts you use here. My math knowledge goes as far as quaternions, linear algebra, partial equations, derivatives and integrals.

Answer (score 1):

What Brian Greene is on about here is that in relativity, we assign to any pair of events an **interval** value, $s^2$.

If there had been (at least) one participant (say, $A$) present ot both events (say event $\varepsilon_{AP}$, the meeting of $A$ and participant $P$; and event $\varepsilon_{AQ}$, the meeting of $A$ and participant $Q$) then the interval is called **timelike**, and we assign (as a suitable convention) the interval value $$s^2[~\text{timelike pair } \varepsilon_{AP}, \varepsilon_{AQ}~] := (\text{Max}[~\tau A[~{}_{\circ P}, {}_{\circ Q}~]~])^2,$$
the square of the maximum duration of all participants at both events, from the indication of having met (and left) $P$, until the indication of having (reached and) met $Q$.

If, for some (other) pair of events (say event $\varepsilon_{JK}$ and event $\varepsilon_{AQ}$), nobody had taken part in both events, but the signal indications of participants in one event had been observed by the participants in the other event, then these two events are called **lightlike** to each other, and we assign to this pair of events the interval value $s^2[~\text{lightlike pair }\varepsilon_{JK}, \varepsilon_{AQ}~] = 0$.

And otherwise the pair of events under consideration (say event $\varepsilon_{JK}$ and event $\varepsilon_{FQ}$) is called **spacelike** related to each other; and (at least when considering events in a flat region) their interval value is assigned as $$s^2[~\text{spacelike pair }\varepsilon_{JK}, \varepsilon_{FQ}~] = -(\text{Max}[~\tau_{\text{ping}}~])^2,$$
the square of the maximum ping duration between pairs of participants at either event who remained at rest to each other;
which is attained for, say, the pair $J$ and $Q$: $$\text{Max}[~\tau_{\text{ping}}~] = \tau J[~{}_{\circ K}, {}_{\circledR Q \circledR J \circ K}~] = \tau Q[~{}_{\circ F}, {}_{\circledR J \circledR Q \circ F}~].$$

(The distance of $J$ and $Q$ wrt. each other is thus of course expressed as $$c/2~\tau J[~{}_{\circ K}, {}_{\circledR Q \circledR J \circ K}~] = c/2~\tau Q[~{}_{\circ F}, {}_{\circledR J \circledR Q \circ F}~],$$
where "$c$" is a non-zero symbol.)

If the region containing the events under consideration was flat then in particular $$\tau Q[~{}_{\circ F}, {}_{\circledR J \circledR Q \circ F}~] = 2~\tau Q[~{}_{\circ F}, {}_{\circ A}~],$$

and thus

$$s^2[~\varepsilon_{JK}, \varepsilon_{FQ}~] = -s^2[~\varepsilon_{FQ}, \varepsilon_{AQ}~],$$

together with $s^2[~\varepsilon_{JK}, \varepsilon_{AQ}~] = 0$ from above.

If we further require that the three events $\varepsilon_{JK}$, $\varepsilon_{AP}$ and $\varepsilon_{FQ}$ are straight wrt. each other, and in this (spatial) order, i.e.

$$\sqrt{-s^2[~\varepsilon_{JK}, \varepsilon_{AP}~]} + \sqrt{-s^2[~\varepsilon_{AP}, \varepsilon_{FQ}~]} = \sqrt{-s^2[~\varepsilon_{JK}, \varepsilon_{FQ}~]} = \sqrt{s^2[~\varepsilon_{FQ}, \varepsilon_{AQ}~]}, $$

then we can express the speed of $A$ wrt. the inertial system $\mathcal S$ constituted of members $J$ and $Q$ (among others) as

$$v_{\mathcal S}[~A~] := c~\sqrt{\frac{-s^2[~\varepsilon_{AP}, \varepsilon_{FQ}~]}{s^2[~\varepsilon_{FQ}, \varepsilon_{AQ}~]}} = c~\sqrt{\frac{s^2[~\varepsilon_{AP}, \varepsilon_{FQ}~]}{s^2[~\varepsilon_{JK}, \varepsilon_{FQ}~]}}.$$

Finally, from the (chrono-geometric) definition of "flatness" (or specificly: "planeness") of four events in terms of the vanishing of the corresponding Cayley-Menger determinant:

$$ 
0 = \begin{Vmatrix}
0 & s^2[~\varepsilon_{JK}, \varepsilon_{AP}~] & s^2[~\varepsilon_{JK}, \varepsilon_{FQ}~] & s^2[~\varepsilon_{JK}, \varepsilon_{AQ}~] & 1 ~ \cr
s^2[~\varepsilon_{JK}, \varepsilon_{AP}~] & 0 & s^2[~\varepsilon_{AP}, \varepsilon_{FQ}~] & s^2[~\varepsilon_{AP}, \varepsilon_{AQ}~] & 1 ~ \cr
s^2[~\varepsilon_{JK}, \varepsilon_{FQ}~] & s^2[~\varepsilon_{AP}, \varepsilon_{FQ}~] & 0 & s^2[~\varepsilon_{FQ}, \varepsilon_{AQ}~] & 1 ~ \cr
s^2[~\varepsilon_{JK}, \varepsilon_{AQ}~] & s^2[~\varepsilon_{AP}, \varepsilon_{AQ}~] & s^2[~\varepsilon_{FQ}, \varepsilon_{AQ}~] & 0 & 1 ~ \cr
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 ~ 
\end{Vmatrix}, $$

$$ \scriptsize{
0 = \begin{Vmatrix}
0 & \!\!\sqrt{-s^2[~\varepsilon_{AP}, \varepsilon_{FQ}~]} - \sqrt{s^2[~\varepsilon_{FQ}, \varepsilon_{AQ}~]}\!\! & \!-s^2[~\varepsilon_{FQ}, \varepsilon_{AQ}~] \! & 0 & 1 ~ \cr
\sqrt{-s^2[~\varepsilon_{AP}, \varepsilon_{FQ}~]} - \sqrt{s^2[~\varepsilon_{FQ}, \varepsilon_{AQ}~]} \!\! & 0 & \! s^2[~\varepsilon_{AP}, \varepsilon_{FQ}~] \! & s^2[~\varepsilon_{AP}, \varepsilon_{AQ}~] & 1 ~ \cr
-s^2[~\varepsilon_{FQ}, \varepsilon_{AQ}~] & s^2[~\varepsilon_{AP}, \varepsilon_{FQ}~] & 0 & s^2[~\varepsilon_{FQ}, \varepsilon_{AQ}~] & 1 ~ \cr
0 & s^2[~\varepsilon_{AP}, \varepsilon_{AQ}~] & \! s^2[~\varepsilon_{FQ}, \varepsilon_{AQ}~] \! & 0 & 1 ~ \cr  
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 ~ 
\end{Vmatrix}
} $$

it follows:

$$s^2[~\varepsilon_{AP}, \varepsilon_{AQ}~] = s^2[~\varepsilon_{FQ}, \varepsilon_{AQ}~] + s^2[~\varepsilon_{AP}, \varepsilon_{FQ}~],$$

$$\frac{s^2[~\varepsilon_{AP}, \varepsilon_{AQ}~]}{s^2[~\varepsilon_{FQ}, \varepsilon_{AQ}~]} = 1 + \frac{s^2[~\varepsilon_{AP}, \varepsilon_{FQ}~]}{s^2[~\varepsilon_{FQ}, \varepsilon_{AQ}~]} = 1 - \left(\frac{v_{\mathcal S}[~A~]}{c}\right)^2. $$

Now, it seems that in certain popular presentations the expression "$c~\sqrt{\frac{s^2[~\varepsilon_{AP}, \varepsilon_{AQ}~]}{s^2[~\varepsilon_{FQ}, \varepsilon_{AQ}~]}}$"
is called "$A$'s speed through time (in reference to inertial system $\mathcal S$)";
symbolically: "$v_{(\mathcal S \text{ Time})}[~A~]$".

And with this notation we obtain:

$$c = \sqrt{(v_{\mathcal S}[~A~])^2 + (v_{(\mathcal S \text{ Time})}[~A~])^2},$$

for what it's worth.

Comment: That was the most complicated way I have ever seen to observe that the 4-velocity $\gamma [c, \vec v]$ has 4-magnitude speed $c$, such that defining $c/\gamma$ as the particle's "speed through time" $u$ we trivially have (from its 4-product with itself): $c^2 = \gamma^2(c^2 - v^2)$, or dividing by $\gamma^2$ and moving $v^2$ to the left, $u^2 + v^2 = c^2$.

Comment: @Chris Drost: "_That was the most complicated way I have ever seen to observe that the 4-velocity $\gamma~[c,\vec v]$ has 4-magnitude speed $c$, such that [...]_" -- Perhaps you mean compared to any number of other ways which **cut short on deriving** that the relation between speeds such as $c$ and $v$ and a third one in terms of their "_magnitudes_" takes a particular (algebraic) form; namely related to that by $\gamma$ **you mean** $1 / \sqrt{1 - (v/c)^2}$? (In my college days we used to observe that "The sum of all difficulties is a constant.". Google doesn't seem to know that anymore ...)

Answer (score 0):

Although the answers here are good, in my opinion, they're too mathematical for the OP to get it.

Before explaining what Brain Greene intended to convey in his article, I'd like to clear up your misunderstanding.

There's no such thing as "time speed" vs "space speed", speed is the magnitude of one's velocity, and velocity is the rate of change of one's position with respect to time.

Now let me explain What Brian meant when he said that objects are always moving at $c$.

Forget about relativity for a second, How we measure distances in space?(we'll consider 2D space for simplicity).

[image]

To compute the length of the blue segment is pretty straight forward thing to do, you measure the x and y components of the segment and use pythagorean theorem: $ds^2=dy^2+dx^2$.

So the metric(distance function) for a line segment in  ordinary Euclidean space is computed by: $ds^2=dy^2+dx^2$.

There's something important about this equation, different observers will disagree on the $(x,y)$ coordinates of the segment(consider a coordinate $(x',y')$ that is rotated relative to $(x,y)$). But they'll all agree on $ds^2$-the length of the segment squared.

Now in relativity, distances are relative, so observers will disagree on  $ds^2=dy^2+dx^2$.

However there's another quantity that all observers agree on: [image]

In the above picture, there are two observers: you on the left at rest, and your friend on the right who's moving relative to you, starting from $t=0$ I took five moments($t=0,1,2..$) of  space and stacked them up above each other. This is called spacetime.

The amazing thing is that all observers regardless of their velocities agree on the length of the blue segment! This is the trajectory of your friend through spacetime. You'll notice that this is not an ordinary spatial distance, it's not a time interval either, it's a combination of both! and the equation for computing the length of your friend's **spacetime interval** is given by:

$ds^2=-c^2dt^2+dx^2$. It's strikingly similar to the pythagorean theorem.

Your friend's trajectory through spacetime is tilted, but yours is just a straight line through the time-axis. In a very rough and totally imprecise sense, your "whole motion is through time", while your friend is a combination of both.

This is perhaps what Brain meant, an observer's spacetime trajectory at rest is only through time.

What about "objects are always moving at $c$"?

One has to introduce another quantity $d\tau$ called the proper time, for our purposes, you can think of it, as the time the clock of your friend reads in his trajectory through spacetime. And it's related to the metric as follows:

$-c^2d\tau^2=ds^2=-c^2dt^2+dx^2$

With algebraic manipulation one gets: $c^2(\dfrac{d\tau}{dt})^2+(\dfrac{dx}{dt})^2=c^2$

$\dfrac{dx}{dt}$ is your friend's velocity, and $\dfrac{d\tau}{dt}$ is rate at which your fiend clock ticks with respect to your clock at rest.

when your friend's velocity $\dfrac{dx}{dt}$ increases, $\dfrac{d\tau}{dt}$ correspondingly decreases and vice versa, but their sum is always equal to the speed of light(squared).

However this should never be interpreted as $c = spaceSpeed + timeSpeed$. This is dead wrong. there's no such thing as motion through time.

Answer (score -1):

This is a very good example for how tv programs for laymen are doing more harm than good. There is no such thing as "time speed".

Time is that which a clock shows. Period.

Please repeat after me:

Time is that which a clock shows.

Repeat after me:

Time...is...that...which...a (as in ONE)...clock...shows. Any one clock, anywhere, anytime.

Resting clocks have the same "flow of time" for every one of their observers. You could stare at your clock all day long and you wouldn't know how fast you are going RELATIVE to someone else. Why? Because it doesn't matter to your clock. Your clock is not sensitive to "your" velocity or to anybody else's velocity. If you want to measure a velocity you have to make two measurements at different points in space (as defined by a moving yardstick) and at different points in time (as defined by a clock).

And now I would suggest you go back to your classical mechanics textbook from high school and you revisit the chapters about velocity and acceleration and you pay a lot of attention to how those are defined and how they transform from one inertial coordinate system to another inertial coordinate system. Unless you are absolutely  sure you understand how that works it's not even worth taking a look at special relativity and, please, please forget everything you think you have seen on tv.

Comment: This was a rude one

Comment: @AdamSkywalker: Not at all. I didn't blame the OP because (s)he is not at fault. Bad tv programs are. The damage, however, is done and the best thing the OP can do is to start over.

Comment: Bad physicists are doing more harm to the layman, than good. When it was thought that the Earth was at the center of the galaxy, the strange movement of the other planets seemed bizarre, but not bizarre once it was understood that all of our planets orbit our sun. Today, the speed of light is at the center of relativity and thus things about special relativity seem bizarre. However, if the center becomes the ongoing motion of all objects existing within Space-Time, all the bizarreness vanishes. http://goo.gl/fz4R0I